# Pixel 6a does not show available Android security updates

Tags: updates, security, android-12

On a Pixel 6a device, Android seems to have trouble finding the latest security updates.

On the one hand, it warns me under Settings->Security like this:

> (!) Update this device
> This device hasn't had a security update in 90 days
> (Check for updates)

Fair enough, but when I do check for updates Android tells me:

> Your system is up to date
> Android version: 12
> Android security update: 5 April 2022
> Last successful check for update 13:55

(which matches the device's current time)

The expectation is that there is at least one more recent security system update available.

Especially, since a Pixel 3a device I have access to update to the 5th of May 2022 system security update, a few weeks ago.

What gives?

Is there some trick to persuade Android to check - let's say - more thoroughly for system updates?

Comment: Is your phone branded by a MNO? Branded devices often get delayed updates. It is known that the button "Check for updates" does not every time checks for updates. Try to repeat the update check multiple times...

Comment: Checking the official [Factory Images for Nexus and Pixel Devices](https://developers.google.com/android/images#bluejay), looks like there were only 2 images with June 2022 security update: JP carriers and Verizon MVNOs, but no May 2022 images at all.

Comment: @Robert no, it isn't. It's a vanilla device from the google store. I repeated the check 20 times or so today already, including before/after a device reboot.

Comment: @AndrewT. AFAICS, all currently supported Pixel devices should have received the [May](https://source.android.com/security/bulletin/pixel/2022-05-01) and [June](https://source.android.com/security/bulletin/pixel/2022-06-01) monthly security updates, at this point. Looks like the OTA/firmware images are released on a different schedule and thus don't always include all the released security updates.

Comment: According to the news sources ([XDA](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-pixel-6a-first-update/), [Android Police](https://www.androidpolice.com/pixel-6a-gets-its-very-first-update-but-only-to-a-june-patch-level/)), Pixel 6a got the first OTA a few days ago, bumping the security patch from April 2022 directly to June 2022 but not July 2022, and is still only available for JP carriers and Verizon MVNOs (as mentioned on the official page). Also, AFAIK, Google releases factory images at the same time the OTA is first rolling out, so it's usually published quicker than some users getting the OTA

Comment: @AndrewT. ok, then Google's statement on their [bulletin page](https://source.android.com/security/bulletin/pixel) 'These bulletins supplement the Android Security Bulletins with additional security patches and functional improvements on supported Google Pixel and Nexus devices (Google devices). [..] Google devices start receiving OTA updates on the same day the monthly bulletin is released.' promises more than Google delivers. Do you want to post your comments (including the last 2 links) as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statements from Google regarding their update procedures such as

> These bulletins supplement the Android Security Bulletins with additional security patches and functional improvements on supported Google Pixel and Nexus devices (Google devices). [..] Google devices start receiving OTA updates on the same day the monthly bulletin is released.

([source](https://source.android.com/security/bulletin/pixel))

should be taken with a grain of salt.

Clearly, the Pixel 6a is a supported Google Pixel device but didn't receive any OTA updates for May and June updates, even in late July, as reported by tech sites:

- https://www.xda-developers.com/google-pixel-6a-first-update/
- https://www.androidpolice.com/pixel-6a-gets-its-very-first-update-but-only-to-a-june-patch-level/

According to these reports, such a delay of security updates is common with newly released Google devices, and happened with past models, as well, in a similar fashion.

---

FWIW, my Pixel 6a device (bought directly from Google, from Germany) received its first monthly security OTA update on 2022-08-05 - and that's the June 1st update.

Comment: When I contacted support about not getting updates, their response was "wipe to factory reset and restore".  I declined, given the time required to set up apps that are not part of the backup regime.  Shortly after, the device got updated to Android 13 and August 5 patches.  But the September 6 patches still do not show up after 6 days.  My device was purchased unlocked from the Google Store on the July 28th release date.

Comment: It eventually updated.